# AChartEngine Annotations on a TimeChart not working

Tags: android, achartengine

I am having a problem getting annotations to show up on a TimeChart. I have a GraphUtil class that has the following static method that returns a GraphicalView:

```
public static GraphicalView getGraph(Activity activity, XYMultipleSeriesRenderer graphRenderer, XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset, TimeSeries series, XYSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer) {
    dataset.addSeries(series);
    graphRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
    series.addAnnotation("Hi", 100, 100);
    return ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(activity, dataset, graphRenderer, "M/d");
}
```

It is being called from a Fragment, with a method like this:

```
private void initFlexionGraph() {
    mflexionSeries = getFlexionData();
    mflexionDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    mflexionGraphRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mflexionSeriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();

    mflexionGraph = GraphUtil.getGraph(getActivity(), mflexionGraphRenderer, mflexionDataset, mflexionSeries, mflexionSeriesRenderer);
    ((LinearLayout) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.flexion_graph)).addView(mflexionGraph);
}
```

Here is my getFlexionData() method:

```
private TimeSeries getFlexionData() {
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>(count);
    List<Double> flexions = new ArrayList<Double>(count);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
             dates.add(DateUtil.getBeginningCalendarTimeOfDate(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"))).getTime());
             flexions.add(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("best_flexion")));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        TimeSeries flexionSeries = new TimeSeries();
        for (int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++) {
            flexionSeries.add(dates.get(i), flexions.get(i));
        }
    }
    return flexionSeries;
}
```

The rest of the graph shows up great, but no annotations anywhere. I also set some properties for the mflexionSeriesRenderer and the mflexionGraphRenderer, but I omitted them here. I can post them if you think there could be a problem there.

When I go to a different tab and come back, I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at org.achartengine.util.IndexXYMap.getXByIndex(IndexXYMap.java:76)
at org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.getAnnotationX(XYSeries.java:260)
at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.draw(XYChart.java:307)
at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:181)
```

My onResume() method includes this code (this probably isn't an efficient way to repaint, but just calling repaint() doesn't work for me):

```
if (mflexionGraph == null) {
    initFlexionGraph();
} else {
    mflexionSeries = getFlexionData();
    mflexionGraph = GraphUtil.getGraph(getActivity(), mflexionGraphRenderer, mflexionDataset, mflexionSeries, mflexionSeriesRenderer);
    ((LinearLayout) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.flexion_graph)).removeAllViews();
    ((LinearLayout) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.flexion_graph)).addView(flexionGraph);
    mflexionGraph.repaint();
}
```

I'm not sure why the annotation isn't showing up (my LinearLayout is 300 x 300, so a string at (100, 100) should appear). I am using achartengine-1.2.0 (downloaded from the nightly build on 3/24/2014). Any ideas?

Comment: Can u show getFlexionData() method ?

Comment: Edited my post to add the getFlexionData() method.

Comment: Are u getting ur graph correctly ? Can u show a snap ?

Comment: Yes. You can view a screenshot [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2el0zmu8lfpwc1/Progress.png). The green line is what I need the annotation for, but even with all that code removed I still can't get an annotation to show up on the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
    private LinearLayout chartLayout;
    private GraphicalView mChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        showTimeGraph();
    }

    private void showTimeGraph()
    {
        chartLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graphHolder);

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset1 = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

        TimeSeries series1 = new TimeSeries("timeseries");
        series1 = getFlexionData();
//      dataset1.addSeries(0, series1);

        double[] limits = new double[] { 0, 40, 0, 200 };
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        multiRenderer.setChartTitle("Title");
        multiRenderer.setXTitle("x axis");
        multiRenderer.setYTitle("y axis");
        multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
        multiRenderer.setBarSpacing(1);
        multiRenderer.setBarWidth(10);
        multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
        multiRenderer.setYAxisMax(250);
        multiRenderer.setXAxisMin(-1);
        multiRenderer.setXAxisMax(10);
        multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        multiRenderer.setLegendTextSize(20);
        multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(20);
        multiRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        multiRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        multiRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLACK);
        multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
//      multiRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 255, 255));
        multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
        multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLACK);
        multiRenderer.clearXTextLabels();
        // multiRenderer.setYLabels(0); //remove units on the Y axis(the horizontal
        // axis since the graph has been rotated 90 degree)
        // multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        multiRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(-10f); // no effect
        // multiRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(20f);
        // multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{90, 0, 90, 0}); //top, left, bottom,
        // right.
        multiRenderer.setOrientation(org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        incomeRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(20);
        incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        incomeRenderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Align.CENTER);

//      multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
        // NumberFormat noFormat = new DecimalFormat( "##0.#E0" );
        multiRenderer.setYLabels(5);
        // multiRenderer.setYLabelFormat( noFormat ,0);
        multiRenderer.setInScroll(true);

        // multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
        // multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
        multiRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);
        multiRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);
        String[] types = new String[] { BarChart.TYPE };

        // setChartSettings(multiRenderer);
        // Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dataset1,
        // multiRenderer, null);
        // Intent intent = ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartIntent(context, dataset,
        // multiRenderer, types, null);
        // multiRenderer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        // mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context,
        // getBarDataSet(),getBarRenderer() ,null);
        // mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context, dataset1,
        // multiRenderer, null);
         mChart = getGraph(this, multiRenderer, dataset1,series1,incomeRenderer);
//      mChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, dataset1,multiRenderer  , "M/d");// "M/d"

        chartLayout.addView(mChart);
    }

     protected DefaultRenderer buildCategoryRenderer(int[] colors) {
        DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
        for (int color : colors) {
          SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
          r.setColor(color);
          renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }
        return renderer;
      }
    public static GraphicalView getGraph(Activity activity, XYMultipleSeriesRenderer graphRenderer,
            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset, TimeSeries series, XYSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer)
    {
        dataset.addSeries(series);
        graphRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
        seriesRenderer.setAnnotationsColor(Color.BLACK);
        series.addAnnotation("THis is your Annotation", 4, 200);
        return ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(activity, dataset, graphRenderer, "M/d");
    }

private TimeSeries getFlexionData()
    {
        TimeSeries series1 = new TimeSeries("timeseries");
        series1 = new TimeSeries("timeseries");
         long value = new Date().getTime() - 3 * TimeChart.DAY;
        Random rr = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            series1.add( i , 100 + rr.nextInt() % 100);
        }
        return series1;
    }
```

Comment: This works until I put the LinearLayout (R.id.graphHolder) inside a ScrollView. Then nothing shows up. I did add `multiRenderer.setInScroll(true);` as well.

Here's my XML:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/graphHolder"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>`